# Upload File Api request works in postman but not in nodejs and react MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, axios

I am making file upload and media API, in Postman works ok but in code not

React Code:

```
campaignChangedHandler = (event) => {
   this.setState(
        {
            campaignFile: document.getElementById('campaignFile').files[0]
        })
};

onSubmit = async(e) => {
   let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('campaignFile', this.state.campaignFile);

     const headers = {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
     };

      await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/upload/', {formData}, {headers}).then(resp => {
         console.log(resp)
      })
};


render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input value={this.state.data} error={errors.data}
            onChange={this.campaignChangedHandler}
            name={"campaignFile"}
            id="campaignFile"
            type="file"/>
    </form>
  )
}
```

NODE JS code:

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.files);
}
```

I always get UNDEFINED in Nodejs console, I tried with multiparty, multer, busboy, but I get the same result, however in postman i get this:

[response from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhkQk.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        campaignFile: null
      }

  }



 onChangeHandler=event=>{
    this.setState({
      campaignFile: event.target.files[0],
    })
  }



 onSubmit = async(e) => {
   let formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('campaignFile', this.state.selectedFile);

     const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
     };

      await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/upload/',formData,headers).then(resp => {
         console.log(resp)
      })
};


render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input type="file" name="campaignFile" onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: Instead of "try this", how about you actually try **explaining** what part you actually changed and why it is important. Simple blocks of code with no explanation are not really useful ( alone ) to future readers who might have the same problem. They also have the distinct "smell" of code copied from another existing answer if the person answering here is unable to **"explain how it works"**. Good answers explain the reasons **why**.